# How to enable GRPC compression in Go

Tags: go, grpc

I see some methods `WithCompression` and `UseCompression` but I'm not very clear how they all fit together - a simple example of what to put in the client and what to put in the server would really help.

My first attempt,

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(
    addr,
    grpc.WithTimeout(timeout),
    grpc.WithCompressor(grpc.NewGZIPCompressor()),
    ...
```

resulted in this error when I made a call:

```
grpc: Decompressor is not installed for grpc-encoding \"gzip\"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`grpc.WithCompressor` as DialOption is deprecated, according to the docs.

You can use the `grpc.UseCompressor(gzip.Name)` CallOption, which operates at call level

```
var opts []grpc.CallOption
opts = append(callOptions, grpc.UseCompressor(gzip.Name))
opts = append(callOptions, ...)
opts = append(callOptions, ...)

err := grpc.Invoke(mycontext, "/myRpcFuntion", myInput, myOutput, myGrpcConn, opts...)
```

You do not need to call `RegisterCompressor`. The gzip package import does it for you in the `init()` function

```
func init() {
    c := &compressor{}
    c.poolCompressor.New = func() interface{} {
        return &writer{Writer: gzip.NewWriter(ioutil.Discard), pool: &c.poolCompressor}
    }
    encoding.RegisterCompressor(c)
}
```

At the server side, you need to import the `gzip` package to make sure that the gzip compressor is registered.

```
import _ "google.golang.org/grpc/encoding/gzip"
```

Comment: I am using golang to call and using `opts := []grpc.CallOption{grpc.UseCompressor(gzip.Name)}` with import `"google.golang.org/grpc/encoding/gzip"` still I am getting above error. I am not able to figure out what is causing this? any idea?

Comment: I just disabled the compression and it solves the build errors now. if you find out what might be causing this, please do share. this thread is also useful: https://github.com/bradleyjkemp/grpc-tools/issues/19

Answer (score 2):

Doc on the compression APIs can be find at: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/compression.md

Comment: Thanks; this is half-useful since it names functions to call, but it does not show how to use them.
Also "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.